# Extract all seasons and episode video links from CBS website

Tags: parsing, html-parsing

CBS has the TV show "The Challenge", and there are many seasons and many episodes for each season. They are on the CBS website here: https://www.cbs.com/shows/the-challenge/

I would like a list of all the video links, such as this (first 4 episodes of Season 11).

```
https://www.cbs.com/shows/the-challenge/video/C5NCzTv2qJp1GwhcV5KWxeKWN4p6_Mqt/the-challenge-throwing-down-the-gauntlet/
https://www.cbs.com/shows/the-challenge/video/kXdno68B36gd6s06OhdrUDUvAAYY4q_e/the-challenge-derrick-steps-it-up/
https://www.cbs.com/shows/the-challenge/video/RYA43Dqs2bRJsgAtcZIZhN8zVVQ1FIxf/the-challenge-we-can-work-it-out/
https://www.cbs.com/shows/the-challenge/video/lJvc_Lkns9Q2NYkDfmsNQmeajXP3QjRm/the-challenge-the-10-000-pyramid/
```

How can I automatically extract the video links for all of the episodes? I was able to "view page source", but it only showed 12/18 episodes for Season 11: (Open with chrome): view-source:https://www.cbs.com/shows/the-challenge/ , search for `https://www.cbs.com/shows/the-challenge/video`, should show 12 matches.

The page "hides" episodes and seasons inside the main page, so there is not a separate URL for other seasons. The solution I have now is to manually copy the link address for each of the videos...

Comment: Are you using python?

Comment: @JackFleeting I can, is there a good way to do this with python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page is (partially) dynamically loaded using javascript. For example, the links for episodes 13-18 are loaded that way.

To capture those, you'll need to use your browser's Developer tab (that's a long and complicated story; you can start reading about it [here, for example).](https://www.codementor.io/@codementorteam/how-to-scrape-an-ajax-website-using-python-qw8fuitvi)

Once you have that link, the response is a json, which - treated as a python dictionary, yields the desired output.

So all together:

```
import requests
cookies = {
    'CBS_ADV_VAL': 'c',
    'CBS_ADV_SUBSES_VAL': '4',
    'ovvuid': '9f064779-4c06-49f1-9cdd-7e64e653145e',
    'OptanonConsent': 'isIABGlobal=false&datestamp=Wed+Sep+09+2020+15%3A44%3A13+GMT-0400+(Eastern+Daylight+Time)&version=6.5.0&hosts=&consentId=d1c945ba-78ea-46e6-ba6f-5329085e06d8&interactionCount=1&landingPath=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cbs.com%2Fshows%2Fthe-challenge%2F&groups=1%3A1%2C2%3A1%2C3%3A1%2C4%3A1%2C5%3A1',
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Referer': 'https://www.cbs.com/shows/the-challenge/',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'TE': 'Trailers',
}

response = requests.get('https://www.cbs.com/shows/the-challenge/xhr/episodes/page/0/size/18/xs/0/season/11/', headers=headers, cookies=cookies)

links = response.json()
for entry in (links['result']['data']):  
    print(entry['url'])
```

Output:

```
/shows/the-challenge/video/IBWXQxtaPVmI40RnAACOc_zo0u13Ups1/the-challenge-blind-panic/
/shows/the-challenge/video/uFv8wFmvUFRKfiM29HVT3K_gGCZ4IWYS/the-challenge-last-men-standing/
/shows/the-challenge/video/9GP_ASLg9U_MmFvFmXPHO9liRzjdHhwI/the-challenge-don-t-bet-on-it/
```

etc., all 18 episodes. You can then concatenate each of these links with the base url (`https://www.cbs.com`) to form the final links.

Comment: Thanks! I made this work by adding a loop and concatenating the base urls, changing the bottom section of your code to:
```
for i in range(11, 32):
    print("#######   Season " + str(i) + "   #######\n")
    response = requests.get('https://www.cbs.com/shows/the-challenge/xhr/episodes/page/0/size/18/xs/0/season/' + str(i) + '/', headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
    links = response.json()
    for entry in (links['result']['data']):  
        print("https://www.cbs.com" + entry['url'])
```